# Use bubblesort to sort a random number of dynamic array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void bubblesort(double *array, int size);
void showarray(double* array, int size);
void main()
{
int arraysize;
double *iptr = nullptr;
cout << "Enter the array size you want" << endl;
cin >> arraysize;
iptr = new double[arraysize];


for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
{

    iptr[i] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    cout << "Number " << i + 1 << ":" << iptr[i] << endl;
}

cout << "Array after arrange" << endl;
bubblesort(iptr, arraysize);
showarray(iptr, arraysize);

delete[] iptr;
iptr = nullptr;
system("Pause");

}

void bubblesort(double *array, int size){
bool swap;
double temp;
do
{
    swap = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;    
        }
    }
} while (swap);
}
void showarray(double *array, int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    cout << array[i] << " " << endl;
    }
 }
```

This is my small program. I am trying to do a bubblesort function to sort my array of random number. But I keep cannot run the program and i can't find the problem.It keep pop out a windows which triggered breakpoint.

Comment: Probably using the debugger and step through your code will give you results quicker than asking here (supposed your code compiles already).

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: A perfectly reasonable question, gets marked down.

Answer (score 1):

You access to your `array`out of bounds. If your array has N elements the indices of your elements ar 0, 1, 2 .. N-1. Adapt your code like this:

```
void bubblesort(double *array, int size){
    bool swap;
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
                             // ^^ because you access to i+1
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                double temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;    
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function bubblesort there is an attempt to access the memory beyond the array when `i` is equal to `size - 1`

Using your approach the function can be written the following way

```
void bubble_sort( double *a, size_t n )
{
    bool swap;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( a[i] < a[i - 1] )
            {
                double temp = a[i - 1];
                a[i - 1] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
                swap = true;    
            }
        }
    } while ( swap );
}
```

Also it would be more efficient to decrease the upper bound of the array in the function at least after each iteration because elements with higher values will be ordered.

Also take into account the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main()
```